# Not able to see login button in PROD except for two users

Tags: production, grant-login-access, unlimited

I have a PRODUCTION org with unlimited edition and I am trying to login as another user but I am able to see login button for only two users and these users are not system admin. Login button is not available for any of the other users. The user I am trying to login as has the same profile as the one which has a Login button.

What can be the reason and how can i resolve this?

Comment: Which login button? Are you trying to log in as another user?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to login as  another user and referring to Login button on user detail page

Comment: Hey @DavidReed, Please refresh the page to look at edited question.Thanks

Comment: Are the other users active?

Comment: For logging in as another user, your user must have modify all data permission. It might possible that other users have this permission through permission set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally, you can only log in as users that have "Granted Login Access." This is done on a per-user basis by going to "My Settings > Personal > Grant Login Access", and must be done while logged in as that user. There is a feature to enable "[Organization Admins Can Login as Any User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enabling-Organization-Admins-Can-Login-as-Any-User&language=en_US&type=1)". To enable this, go through Setup > Security Controls > Login Access Policies > Administrators Can Log In As Any User > Save. If you don't see this feature, contact Support. Finally, if you're only a Delegated Administrator, you may not be able to log in as any user, since this would have been configured by a System Administrator.

Comment: enabling grant login access for that user works! thanks!